# Cannot get firebaseRef to work with angular2 "Cannot find name 'firebase'."

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, angularfire

We are trying to get this example to run in our Angular 2 app from the angularFire2 api docs: angularfire2.com/api

```
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {FirebaseRef} from 'angularfire2';

class MyComponent {
constructor(@Inject(FirebaseRef) ref:Firebase) {
ref.on('value', this.doSomething);
  }
}
```

but we keep getting a build error "cannot find name Firebase"

Where do we need to define Firebase? Its already defined in typings.json :

```
"ambientDependencies": {
"firebase": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/firebase/firebase.d.ts#64b25f63f0ec821040a5d3e049a976865062ed9d",
"es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654"
```

},

any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You're using an old versioned "environment". Checkout the new Angular CLI for latest updates

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from [an answer to this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/380#issuecomment-234666818) which worked for me when I couldn't get the same code you tried to work.

---

> With Angularfire2, you should not need to write any .on() or .off().
>   You can accomplish the same thing by pointing to a reference and then
>   subscribing to it, like so:

```
let subscription = this.af.database.object('someLocation').subscribe(data=> {
//do something with your data
})
```

> Which is essentially the same as:

```
firebase.database().ref('someLocation').on('value', snapshot=>{
//do something with your data
})
```

Comment: Subscribe, continuously watches for updates. Is there an angularfire2 equivalent for firebase.once(), that retrieves data only once?

Comment: actually figured it out, got to use this.af.database.object('someLocation').take(1).subscribe(...)

Comment: but what if i want to use: ref.on('child_added') ?

Comment: I ask myself the same, should we use raw firebase for this?